# Normalizing year data

Tags: time-series, normalization, interarrival-time

I have a data set in which there are data from

**April 2010 to Dec 2010** ( 9 Months)

Jan 2011 to Dec 2011 (12 Months )

Jan 2012 to Dec 2012 (12 Months)

Jan 2013 to Dec 2013 (12 Months)

Jan 2014 to Dec 2014 (12 Months)

Jan 2015 to Dec 2015 (12 Months)

**Jan 2016 to Mar 2016 (3 Months)**

Each year includes crime year in each month. I want to plot a graph showing crime rate from 2010 to 2016 and display how it increases or decreases. I want to know how would I normalize my data so that these missing months does not effect my visualization .

Am I doing it right by normalizing ?

Please suggest any other aprroach you have . But please note I have to plot it year vs crime rate rather than some other time function like month /vs crime rate.

Comment: Normalization is a technical term that has a very different meaning in statistics than the one you have used. Please rephrase your question using another word other than normalizing, or try to be more clear.

Comment: I think what you want is a monthplot https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/monthplot.html. Missing data usually refers to a time series that is non-contiguous. This is not your case. How is that a problem for a month plot?

Comment: What do you mean by "normalizing" this data? Commonly by "normalizing" people mean subtracting mean and dividing by standard deviation, or dividing by range etc. -- this would not affect anyhow the fact that you have missing data. For missing data you use *imputation* methods.

Comment: I think the meaning of this question is clear even if the language is being used in a non-technical way - the question is how crime data from just part of a year can be used in a plot that shows crime *by year*. It seems the OP wants a way to "scale up" data from part of a year to a whole year.

Comment: One solution, that you might not find acceptable, would be to plot your years as "2010/2011", "2011/2012", "2012/2013" etc, where these annual periods have been defined as running from October of one calendar year (Oct/Nov/Dec = last 3 months of one year) through to September of the next (first 9 months). This would exploit the fact you do have six complete years of data, it's just that they aren't six consecutive *calendar* years.

Comment: Please suggest some good rephrase . I don't know really